# As.array to change data

Tags: r

Very simple concept:

```
data(iris)
d1=as.matrix(iris)
d2=as.array(iris)
Error in <code>dimnames<-.data.framecode>(<code>*tmp*code>, value = list(n)) :invalid 'dimnames' given for data frame
```

i have made many kinds of dimnames ,failed .
how to make as.array(iris) to be successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either choose one of the dimensions (and then you don't even need `as.array`) or you can flatten everything using `c()`. Examples:

```
iris$Petal.Length
c(iris, recursive=T)
```

To get the dimension names you can use in the first case, type `names(iris)`.