# solution of linear programming by R software

Tags: r, linear-programming, simplex

I am trying to solve linear programming problem by R software . I have three files named A.txt, B.txt,F.txt . I have read this by the following code:

```
library( linprog )
Amat<-read.table("D:/Simplex/SimplexInitialTheoryWithRsoftware/src/A.txt",header=FALSE,sep=" ")
bvec<-read.table("D:/Simplex/SimplexInitialTheoryWithRsoftware/src/B.txt",header=FALSE,sep=" ")
cvec<-read.table("D:/Simplex/SimplexInitialTheoryWithRsoftware/src/F.txt",header=FALSE,sep=" ")
```

The link of the file is [A.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByYh8AVRde_Td0hhRnd4Z2dRSXM/edit?usp=sharing) , [B.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByYh8AVRde_TWjZ6bUZRYjZHV0E/edit?usp=sharing) , [F.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByYh8AVRde_TUVNVY0JnZ2RYR2s/edit?usp=sharing) . I am trying to solve this problem by R software by the following code .

```
res <- solveLP( cvec, bvec, Amat, TRUE )
## print the results
print( res )
```

But I am getting the following error .

```
Error in solveLP(cvec, bvec, Amat, TRUE) : 
  Matrix A must have as many rows as constraints (=elements of vector b) and as many columns as variables (=elements of vector c).
```

But I have checked my file again and again . The dimension of A is 10*10 , dimension of B is 10*1 and dimension of F is 1*10 .

So why I am getting the error ?

Update : 
  I have got an error after the following code .

```
cvec<-read.table("D:/Simplex/SimplexInitialTheoryWithRsoftware/src/F.txt",header=FALSE,sep=" ")
```

And the error is

```
   Warning message:
In read.table("D:/Simplex/SimplexInitialTheoryWithRsoftware/src/F.txt",  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'D:/Simplex/SimplexInitialTheoryWithRsoftware/src/F.txt'
```

My assumption is that , the error is caused due to this line of code .

Comment: The documentation (and even the parameter names) is very specific. The first two parameters must be vectors and the third a matrix. You are passing data.frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Roland's comment, the error comes indeed from incorrect specification of the input objects. The code below is tried and tested:

```
library( linprog )
Amat<-as.matrix(read.table("C:\\Users\\ifragkos\\Documents\\Fun\\R\\A.txt",header=FALSE,sep=" "))
bvec<-c(read.table("C:\\Users\\ifragkos\\Documents\\Fun\\R\\B.txt",header=FALSE,sep=" "), recursive=T)
cvec<-c(read.table("C:\\Users\\ifragkos\\Documents\\Fun\\R\\F.txt",header=FALSE,sep=" "), recursive=T)
res<-solveLP(cvec, bvec, Amat, TRUE)
## print the results
print( res )
```

Result:

```
All Variables (including slack variables)
              opt   cvec      min.c      max.c       marg  marg.reg
V1      0.2374153  29.02  21.255258  73.654167         NA        NA
V2      0.0000000  47.98       -Inf  79.114957  -31.13496 0.0672461
V3      0.0000000 -37.64       -Inf  53.342215  -90.98222 0.0751398
V4      0.0000000 -22.01       -Inf  95.534330 -117.54433 0.0529444
V5      0.0000000  -1.36       -Inf  45.246038  -46.60604 0.1159432
V6      0.0000000   4.72       -Inf  55.904385  -51.18439 0.0139935
V7      0.0000000  19.67       -Inf 122.901935 -103.23194 0.0450489
V8      0.0000000  24.32       -Inf  93.315656  -68.99566 0.0420672
V9      0.0000000  46.15       -Inf  57.745346  -11.59535 0.0444139
V10     0.0132743  48.21  18.994909  87.790333         NA        NA
S V11  20.1358135   0.00  -0.497478   0.546882    0.00000        NA
S V12  24.2133223   0.00 -10.046381   0.432213    0.00000        NA
S V13  44.8115881   0.00         NA   0.155625    0.00000        NA
S V14  75.7667354   0.00  -1.509427   0.454518    0.00000        NA
S V15   1.3688361   0.00  -0.826885   0.312089    0.00000        NA
S V16  66.5207843   0.00         NA   0.123910    0.00000        NA
S V17  47.0617343   0.00         NA   0.181379    0.00000        NA
S V18   0.0000000   0.00       -Inf   0.456100   -0.45610 0.8502727
S V19   0.0000000   0.00       -Inf   1.084168   -1.08417 2.8651162
S V110 72.7149517   0.00  -0.919381   0.124553    0.00000        NA
```

**Disclaimer**:This is my first post in `R`, I am by no means an `R` expert. Based on the `linprog API` and @Roland's comment, I did a bit of tweaking of [`as.vector`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/vector.html), looked up the examples of the [linprog reference](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/linprog/linprog.pdf), and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881314/as-array-to-change-data) and came up with the above suggestion.

[The reference of the c() function](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/c) explains that `recursive = TRUE` "recursively descends through lists (and pairlists) combining all their elements into a vector." Omitting the recursion leads to the default `recursive = FALSE`, which results in the whole dataframe being returned as one element only:

```
# This one gives a proper vector
>bvec<-c(read.table("C:\\Users\\ifragkos\\Documents\\Fun\\R\\B.txt",
  header=FALSE,sep=" "), recursive=T)
>bvec
V11   V12   V13   V14   V15   V16   V17   V18   V19  V110 
28.60 34.69 63.04 84.67 12.78 85.24 61.21  7.50  3.79 93.81

# This gives one element only
>bvec<-c(read.table("C:\\Users\\ifragkos\\Documents\\Fun\\R\\B.txt",
  header=FALSE,sep=" "))
>bvec
[1] 28.60 34.69 63.04 84.67 12.78 85.24 61.21  7.50  3.79 93.81
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I got that as well. Open `F.text`, place the cursor at the very end of line 1 and hit enter. Save the file, and the warning will go away. Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990654/incomplete-final-line-warning-when-trying-to-read-a-csv-file-into-r) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help . It helps me a lot . The last word is , you are cordially invited for a treat . Contact with me if you ever visit Bangladesh .

Comment: loannis , This package fails to solve lp problem when the rhs of constraint is negatiev . Why ?

Comment: Did you check that the program you are trying to solve is actually feasible? If you do `[x,lambda,exitflag] = linprog(...)` then `exitflag` will [show the exit condition](https://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/toolbox/optim/linprog.html).